# How to integrate $\int (P(x))^{-1}dx$?

Tags: integration

How to integrate
$$\int \frac{dx}{P_n(x)}, \quad P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$
when $n>2$ and polynomial has no real roots?

I have a feeling that I should know this, but I genuinely cannot remember (don't have to deal with integrals on a regular basis).

Edit: A random example
$$\int \frac{dx}{10 x^4+x^3+x^2+x+10}$$

Comment: Over any particular interval?

Comment: Partial fractions will do the trick.  Google them, there are a thousand sites which cover them and how to separate the integral into one of a sum involving reciprocals of quadratics and linear terms.

Comment: @RonGordon I don't have any specific exercise in mind. But we can say over an arbitrary interval $(\alpha ; \beta)$.

Comment: Perhaps use contour integration with Residue Theorem, closing the contour in some convenient way.

Comment: @muzzlator So I should separate the integral by introducing a bunch of complex numbers? Yet for any arbitrary interval a definite integral becomes real-valued again? Please see added example in my original post.

Comment: You don't need to introduce complex numbers but yes, they will go away if you wanted that.  You can write rational expression as sums of the form $\dfrac{c}{(x - a)^n}$ and  $\dfrac{cx + d}{((x-a)^2 + b)^n}$.  These all have standard integrals (but they get a bit harder for repeated roots of the quadratic kind although still possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$10x^4+x^3+x^2+x+10=0 \ \leftrightarrow \ 10x^2+x+1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{10}{x^2}=0 \ \leftrightarrow \ y+10(y^2-2)+1=0 $

$\{ x+\frac{1}{x}=y \ \to \ x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=y^2-2 \}$